# Como posicionar o texto do lado direito dessa section? Usei"float: right;",mas fica com esse espaço em branco, estou usando o Bootstrap para os textos

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

```js
//Caso aja algum script que me ajude, adoraria saber. Obrigado //pela atenção pessoal :)
```

```css
body{
    background: #24282f;
}

/*GALERIA DE IMAGEM*/
.galeria-second{
    width: 42%;
    height: 530px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 2%;
    
}

.foto-second{
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    animation-name: animacao;
    animation-duration: 20s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    width: 42%;
    height: 530px;
    
}

/*ANIMAÇÃO DE TRANSIÇÃO DAS IMAGENS*/
.foto-second:nth-child(1){
    opacity: 1;
}
  
.foto-second:nth-child(2){
    animation-delay: 5s;
}
  
.foto-second:nth-child(3){
    animation-delay: 10s;
}
  
.foto-second:nth-child(4){
    animation-delay: 15s;
}
  
@keyframes animacao{
    25%{
        opacity: 1;
        
    }
    50%{
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

/*PARTE DOS PARÁGRAFOS*/
p#teste1{
    color: black;
    font-style: italic;
    font-family: Roboto;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    width: 55%;
    float: right;
    
}

p#teste2{
    color: black;
    font-style: italic;
    font-family: Roboto;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    width: 55%;
    float: right;
}

p#teste3{
    color: black;
    font-style: italic;
    font-family: Roboto;
    padding-left: 40px;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 20px;
    width: 55%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Página para Testes</title>
  
  <!-- Linkando a estilização do Bootstrap -->
  <!-- Nessa parte da minha página eu a usei para a criação dos parágrafos, 
  cuja as classes são "lead" por padrão do Bootstrap -->

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
  
  <!-- Seção de imagens, feito sem Bootstrap -->
  <!-- Estou criando um site sobre RPG, por isso as imagens são desse estilo XD -->
  <section class="galeria-second">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/0b/79/cd/0b79cd5f63eec0264f6495ee72ec364e.jpg" width="100%" height="530px" class="foto-second"> 
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/f3/f1/c6/f3f1c623a56ca5ab7f8966f423e22bbb.jpg" width="100%" height="530px" class="foto-second"> 
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/80/ed/70/80ed70dc9cf6509d9fde5ac668c2ad76.jpg" width="100%" height="530px" class="foto-second"> 
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/cf/ea/50/cfea509e8b8d8c74ded792265720feb7.jpg" width="100%" height="530px" class="foto-second"> 
  </section> 

  <!-- Parte dos textos que foram feitos utilizando a classe "lead" do bootstrap -->
  <p class="lead" id="teste1">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam condimentum lobortis nulla eu imperdiet. Morbi a neque id dolor pulvinar mollis. Sed condimentum sed tellus vel malesuada. Aliquam ex lacus, posuere nec ipsum sed, dictum malesuada nisl. Aenean a ligula pretium, tristique velit sed, scelerisque tortor. Proin feugiat egestas neque et lacinia. Nullam hendrerit risus auctor, ornare mi nec, viverra nisl. Donec congue erat quis nisi ultricies porttitor.

  </p>
  <p class="lead" id="teste2">
    Cras ut congue est. Mauris vel lectus mollis, gravida neque sit amet, convallis sapien. Vestibulum laoreet neque at erat rhoncus vehicula id eget diam. Phasellus volutpat, ipsum a feugiat commodo, neque nisi interdum arcu, vel varius risus tortor eget mauris. Mauris scelerisque est vel lacus cursus, quis vulputate nisi vestibulum. Praesent pulvinar pharetra urna, et lacinia sapien porttitor eget. Aenean tristique felis sit amet purus posuere ultricies. Nunc tristique, est id dapibus bibendum, justo ante varius lacus, eu tincidunt mi libero nec metus. Quisque vel euismod neque. Etiam nec eros est. Sed ac ipsum ut enim interdum sagittis. Nullam eu sollicitudin tellus, at fringilla nisi. Phasellus tincidunt dolor sapien, vitae pellentesque leo ultrices quis. Duis consequat id ante ut accumsan.
  </p>
  <p class="lead" id="teste3">
    Nulla faucibus tortor turpis, ac fringilla nunc tristique sit amet. Suspendisse molestie mollis nulla, eget vestibulum massa tristique quis. Phasellus eget consequat lectus. Vestibulum vehicula libero vitae leo suscipit vestibulum. Nulla facilisi. Nullam ultricies dolor et leo pharetra, eget vehicula metus congue. Donec venenatis nec risus eu tristique. Etiam non rhoncus nibh, quis lobortis lacus. Donec erat ipsum, eleifend sodales pretium vitae, pharetra vel nunc. Phasellus libero nisl, porta non facilisis eget, tincidunt a augue. Fusce placerat justo nunc, ac dapibus nunc vehicula non.
  </p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seja bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow!

Eu não precisei alterar em nada o seu css. Por estar utilizando Bootstrap fica bem mais fácil fazer o que você precisa.

Eu apenas inseri um `<main>`para englobar tudo e utilizei a classe `d-flex`.

A documentação completa a respeito, você encontra aqui: [Flex - Bootstrap v5.0](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/)

```css
body {
  background: #24282f;
}


/*GALERIA DE IMAGEM*/

.galeria-second {
  width: 42%;
  height: 530px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 2%;
}

.foto-second {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  animation-name: animacao;
  animation-duration: 20s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  width: 42%;
  height: 530px;
}


/*ANIMAÇÃO DE TRANSIÇÃO DAS IMAGENS*/

.foto-second:nth-child(1) {
  opacity: 1;
}

.foto-second:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 5s;
}

.foto-second:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 10s;
}

.foto-second:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 15s;
}

@keyframes animacao {
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}


/*PARTE DOS PARÁGRAFOS*/

p#teste1 {
  color: black;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: Roboto;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  width: 55%;
  float: right;
}

p#teste2 {
  color: black;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: Roboto;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  width: 55%;
  float: right;
}

p#teste3 {
  color: black;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: Roboto;
  padding-left: 40px;
  float: right;
  padding-right: 20px;
  width: 55%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Página para Testes</title>

  <!-- Linkando a estilização do Bootstrap -->
  <!-- Nessa parte da minha página eu a usei para a criação dos parágrafos, 
  cuja as classes são "lead" por padrão do Bootstrap -->

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
  <main class="d-flex">
    <section class="galeria-second">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/0b/79/cd/0b79cd5f63eec0264f6495ee72ec364e.jpg" width="100%" height="530px" class="foto-second">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/f3/f1/c6/f3f1c623a56ca5ab7f8966f423e22bbb.jpg" width="100%" height="530px" class="foto-second">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/80/ed/70/80ed70dc9cf6509d9fde5ac668c2ad76.jpg" width="100%" height="530px" class="foto-second">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/cf/ea/50/cfea509e8b8d8c74ded792265720feb7.jpg" width="100%" height="530px" class="foto-second">
    </section>

    <!-- Parte dos textos que foram feitos utilizando a classe "lead" do bootstrap -->
    <article>
      <p class="lead" id="teste1">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam condimentum lobortis nulla eu imperdiet. Morbi a neque id dolor pulvinar mollis. Sed condimentum sed tellus vel malesuada. Aliquam ex lacus, posuere nec ipsum sed, dictum malesuada nisl.
        Aenean a ligula pretium, tristique velit sed, scelerisque tortor. Proin feugiat egestas neque et lacinia. Nullam hendrerit risus auctor, ornare mi nec, viverra nisl. Donec congue erat quis nisi ultricies porttitor.

      </p>
      <p class="lead" id="teste2">
        Cras ut congue est. Mauris vel lectus mollis, gravida neque sit amet, convallis sapien. Vestibulum laoreet neque at erat rhoncus vehicula id eget diam. Phasellus volutpat, ipsum a feugiat commodo, neque nisi interdum arcu, vel varius risus tortor eget
        mauris. Mauris scelerisque est vel lacus cursus, quis vulputate nisi vestibulum. Praesent pulvinar pharetra urna, et lacinia sapien porttitor eget. Aenean tristique felis sit amet purus posuere ultricies. Nunc tristique, est id dapibus bibendum,
        justo ante varius lacus, eu tincidunt mi libero nec metus. Quisque vel euismod neque. Etiam nec eros est. Sed ac ipsum ut enim interdum sagittis. Nullam eu sollicitudin tellus, at fringilla nisi. Phasellus tincidunt dolor sapien, vitae pellentesque
        leo ultrices quis. Duis consequat id ante ut accumsan.
      </p>
      <p class="lead" id="teste3">
        Nulla faucibus tortor turpis, ac fringilla nunc tristique sit amet. Suspendisse molestie mollis nulla, eget vestibulum massa tristique quis. Phasellus eget consequat lectus. Vestibulum vehicula libero vitae leo suscipit vestibulum. Nulla facilisi. Nullam
        ultricies dolor et leo pharetra, eget vehicula metus congue. Donec venenatis nec risus eu tristique. Etiam non rhoncus nibh, quis lobortis lacus. Donec erat ipsum, eleifend sodales pretium vitae, pharetra vel nunc. Phasellus libero nisl, porta
        non facilisis eget, tincidunt a augue. Fusce placerat justo nunc, ac dapibus nunc vehicula non.
      </p>
    </article>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Obrigado mano, ajudou muito aqui !